# ERRORES PHP: Undefined index y PDOStatement::execute()

Tags: php, json, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, fullcalendar

*Buenas noches necesito que porfavor me ayuden con este codigo ya que he intentado pero no he podida dar solucion.*
**El codigo del primer doc es el siguiente:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
        <div class="col-7"><div id="CalendarioWeb"></div></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar({
        header:{
            left:'today,prev,next,Miboton',
            center:'title',
            right:'month,basicWeek, basicDay,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
        },
        customButtons:{
            Miboton:{
                text:"Boton 1",
                click:function(){
                    alert("Accion del boton");
                }
            }
        },
        dayClick:function(date,jsEvent,view){
            $('#fecha-inicio').val(date.format());
            $("#formulario-modal").modal();
        },
        events:'http://localhost/MafekingOnline/Calendario.php',
        eventClick:function(calEvent,jsEvent,view){
            $('#titulo-evento').html(calEvent.title);

            $('#id').val(calEvent.id);
            $('#nombre').val(calEvent.title);
            $('#tipo').val(calEvent.Tipo);
            $('#lugar').val(calEvent.Lugar);
            $('#fecha-encuentro').val(calEvent.fechaencuentro);
            $('#hora-encuentro').val(calEvent.horaencuentro);
            $('#punto-encuentro').val(calEvent.puntoencuentro);
            $('#material-individual').val(calEvent.materialindividual);
            $('#material-equipo').val(calEvent.materialequipo);
            $('#ficha').val(calEvent.ficha);
            FechaHoraInicio = calEvent.start._i.split(" ");
            $('#fecha-inicio').val(FechaHoraInicio[0]);
            $('#hora-inicio').val(FechaHoraInicio[1]);
            FechaHoraFin = calEvent.end._i.split(" ");
            $('#fecha-fin').val(FechaHoraFin[0]);
            $('#hora-fin').val(FechaHoraFin[1]);
            $("#formulario-modal").modal();
        }
    });
});
</script>

<!-- Formulario Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="formulario-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="titulo-evento"></h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    Id: <input type="text" id="id" name="id"><br>
    Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br>
    Fecha inicio: <input type="text" id="fecha-inicio" name="fecha-inicio"><br>
    Hora inicio: <input type="text" id="hora-inicio" name="hora-inicio" value="14:30"><br>
    Fecha fin: <input type="text" id="fecha-fin" name="fecha-fin"><br>
    Hora fin: <input type="text" id="hora-fin" name="hora-fin" value="18:30"><br>
    Tipo: <input type="text" id="tipo" name="tipo"><br>
    Lugar: <input type="text" id="lugar" name="lugar"><br>
    Fecha encuentro: <input type="text" id="fecha-encuentro" name="fecha-encuentro"><br>
    Hora encuentro: <input type="text" id="hora-encuentro" name="hora-encuentro"><br>
    Punto encuentro: <input type="text" id="punto-encuentro" name="punto-encuentro"><br>
    Material individual: <input type="text" id="material-individual" name="material-individual"><br>
    Material equipo: <input type="text" id="material-equipo" name="material-equipo"><br>
    Ficha: <input type="text" id="ficha" name="ficha"><br>
    </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="boton-agregar" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Modificar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var NuevoEvento;
$('#boton-agregar').click(function(){
obtenerDatosGUI();
$('#CalendarioWeb').fullCalendar('renderEvent', NuevoEvento);
$("#formulario-modal").modal('toggle');
});

function obtenerDatosGUI(){
NuevoEvento= {
    id:$('#id').val(),
    title:$('#nombre').val(),
    start:$('#fecha-inicio').val()+" "+$('#hora-inicio').val(),
    end:$('#fecha-fin').val()+" "+$('#hora-fin').val(),
    Tipo:$('#tipo').val(),
    Lugar:$('#lugar').val(),
    Fecha_encuentro:$('#fecha-encuentro').val(),
    Hora_encuentro:$('#hora-encuentro').val(),
    Punto_encuentro:$('#punto-encuentro').val(),
    Material_individual:$('#material-individual').val(),
    Material_equipo:$('#material-equipo').val(),
    Ficha:$('#ficha').val(),
    color:"yellow",
    textColor:"black",
};
}
</script>
```

**El codigo PHP del segundo doc es el siguiente:**

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scouts_601_palmira", "root", 
"");
$accion = (isset($_GET['accion']))?$_GET['accion']:'leer';
switch ($accion) {
case 'agregar':
// Agregar
$sentenciaSQL = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO eventos(title, start, end, Tipo, Lugar, Fecha_encuentro, Punto_ecuentro, Material_individual, Material_equipo, Ficha, color, textColor) VALUES(:title, :start, :end, :Tipo, :Lugar, :Fecha_encuentro, :Punto_ecuentro, :Material_individual, :Material_equipo, :Ficha, :color, :textColor)");
$respuesta = $sentenciaSQL->execute(array(
"title" => $_POST['title'],
"start" => $_POST['start'],
"end" => $_POST['end'],
"Tipo" => $_POST['Tipo'],
"Lugar" => $_POST['Lugar'],
"Fecha_encuentro" => $_POST['Fecha_encuentro'],
"Punto_encuentro" => $_POST['Punto_encuentro'],
"Material_individual" => $_POST['Material_individual'],
"Material_equipo" => $_POST['Material_equipo'],
"Ficha" => $_POST['Ficha'],
"color" => "green",
"textColor" => "white",
));
echo json_encode($respuesta);
break;
case 'modificar':
// code...
echo "Instruccion modificar";
break;
case 'eliminar':
// code...
echo "Instruccion eliminar";
break;
default:
//seleccionar los eventos del calendario
$sentenciaSQL= $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM Eventos");
$sentenciaSQL->execute();
$resultado = $sentenciaSQL->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultado);
break;
}
```

Los errores que arroja son:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: title in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **13**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index: start in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **14**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index: end in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **15**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index: Tipo in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **16**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index: Lugar in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **17**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index:
>   Fecha_encuentro in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **18**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index:
>   Punto_encuentro in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **19**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index:
>   Material_individual in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **20**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index:
>   Material_equipo in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **21**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index: Ficha in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **22**
>  
>  **Warning**:  PDOStatement::execute():
>   SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
>   in **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **24**
>  false
>  **Warning**:  Use of undefined constant
>    - assumed '' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\MafekingOnline\Calendario.php** on line
>   **43**

Comment: Parece que los datos no se están enviando. Puedes hacer lo siguiente: `var NuevoEvento= obtenerDatosGUI();`  y agregar un `return` al final de la función donde creas los datos: `function obtenerDatosGUI(){
var NuevoEvento= {
    id:$('#id').val(),   //... return NuevoEvento; }` Desde PHP puedes verificar lo que estás recibiendo haciendo un `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Lo he probado pero no funciona, me quita los errores sí pero no me inserta los valores en la base de datos :(

Comment: Bueno si tu código es mejorable en varios puntos, cuando encontremos la causa principal del problema ... ¿Qué arroja el `var_dump`? Si puedes revisa también el error log.

Comment: Hola, pues al final lo que me imprimia los datos que ingresaba, pero no me dio resultado después de tanto buscar, decidi pasar de JavaScript y trabajar solo en HTML y PHP, donde ya me funciono :)
REITERO AGRADECIMIENTOS.

Comment: Para todas las personas que tenga el mismo error y no den con la solución. **Yo utilice fullcalendar solo para mostrar eventos consultados a la db, pero para el CRUD utilice un calendario creado con HTML.**